# Prove $i_*$ is an embedding

Tags: differential-geometry, proof-verification, vector-space-isomorphism

I'm stuck in this problem:

> "Let $i:S^2\rightarrow \mathbb{R}^3$ the inclusion. Prove that the map $i_{*}:TS^2\rightarrow T\mathbb{R}^3$ is an embedding".

I consider $p=(x_1,x_2,x_3)\in S^2$ and $X=(X^1,X^2,X^3)\in TS^2$, so
\begin{array}{crcl}
i: &S^2 & \longrightarrow & \mathbb{R}^3 \\
 & p & \longmapsto & i(p)=p
\end{array}
and
\begin{array}{crcl}
i_*: & TS^2 & \longrightarrow & T\mathbb{R}^3 \\
 & (p,X) & \longmapsto & \big(i(p),i_{*p}(X)\big)=\big(p, J_i X^T\big)
\end{array}
where $J_i$ is the Jacobian matrix of $i$. If we compute the Jacobian matrix of $i_*$, we get
\begin{equation}J_{i_*}=\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
\frac{\partial(x_1,x_2,x_3)}{\partial (x_1,x_2,x_3)} & \frac{\partial (x_1,x_2,x_3)}{\partial (X^1,X^2,X^3)} \\
\frac{\partial J_i X^T}{\partial (x_1,x_2,x_3)} & \frac{\partial J_i X^T}{\partial (X^1,X^2,X^3)}
\end{array}
\right)=\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
J_i & 0 \\
\frac{\partial J_i X^T}{\partial (x_1,x_2,x_3)} & J_i
\end{array}
\right)
\end{equation}
Since $i$ is an embedding, it's an immersione and then $J_i$ has full rank, per columns, $rank(J_i)=\dim(S^2)$. So we have that $J_{i_*}$ has full rank, per columns, $rank(J_{i_*})=\dim(TS^2)$ and then $i_*$ is an immersion.

Now I just need to prove that $i_*$ is a homeomorphism into its image, or even just that $i_*(TS^2)$ is an embedded submanifold.

So the question is: how can I prove that $i_*(TS^2)$ is an embedded submanifold?

Thank you so much

Comment: $i_*$ is not an isomorphism. These tangent bundles have different dimensions.

Comment: You are absolutely right, so it seems that both my strategies are wrong. I would really appreciate if you could give me an hint to solve this problem. Thank you

Comment: I edited my question.